# Top fixed menu with horizontal scroll in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created top menu bar with horizontal scroll, the `top` property is being set via JS:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#headers').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

The problem is when I'm scrolling the page vertically in IE, menu bar is trying to scroll too and it doesn't look good. Any ideas to fix that?

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/31/)

Comment: You need to work on the content only, I mean just try to move the contents and not header

Answer (score 0):

does this give you the desired output?

```
#headers {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No, now I can't scroll horizontally. The behavior of menu bar is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/khristopherallen/f15vybt7/

If you change your `#headers` to a fixed position, then the jQuery should not be necessary. You then just need to add some margin to the top of your page so the content doesn't start under the header.

```
#headers {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:600;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I now, but it can't be fixed. In this project menu must have constant width and it must be scrollable.

Comment: @MlodyOfSteel, what do you mean by scrollable? In my answer, when you scroll down, the menu is static at the top, with the content flowing under the menu.

Comment: I mean scrollable horizontally, when the menu is wider than the browser window. In IE11 (Win7) you can see jumpy menu when scrolling down/up.